How can I check the value of a paragraph field in Drupal?
I'm new to Drupal, however I need to do the following:
I have a paragraph named ad_section with 2 fields: field_link (type: Plain Text) and field_video (type: Media->Video)
It's necessary that a check occurs on the page where this paragraph is displayed: if the field_video field is filled with a video file attached to it, then add the has-video class to , and if this field is empty and left blank, then add the no-video class to 
Now in html.html.twig classes for  are output like this:
{%
  set body_classes = [
    logged_in ? 'user-logged-in'
  ]
%}
...
<body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }}>

As I understand it, this can be done through the preprocess functions in my customtheme.theme file
But when I try to send a class to  from such a function (even without any logic) nothing happens:
function constructor_preprocess__paragraph__ad_section__field_video(&$variables) {
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'just-test';
}

These options also don't give any result:
function constructor_preprocess__ad_section__field_video(&$variables) {
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'just-test';
}

function constructor_preprocess_field_video(&$variables) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'just-test';
}

function constructor_preprocess_paragraph__ad_section(&$variables) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'just-test';
}

There are two questions:

How do I properly implement the preprocess function for my paragraph so that I can get data from there in a twig template?
And how can I check for an attached video file in such a function?


Although not what you are asking for, I’ve been using less and less of these has-xyz classes in favor of the :has() pseudo class/function: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/NWQzzwM

@Chris Haas sure, but this is where the backend solution is needed exactly)
